# Single Sign on for office 365 outlook

Tags: javascript, azure, visual-studio-2013

Hi there? Can anybody help me to apply single sign on for my office 365 outlook application using azure active directory as idp.

It goes like when I log on to my office 365 account my outlook application will automatically sign in too.

Badly need help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Active Directory Federation services and once that done, assuming that both your Office 365 instance and Outlook use the same AD, you should be all set. Here is a step by step guide to [configure ADFS](http://miniorange.com/using-active-directory-federation-services-for-%28sso%29).

In case you need to configure SAML based SSO for your Office 365 instance, you can use [this other guide as well](http://miniorange.com/office-365-single-sign-on-%28sso%29).

Let me know if this helps and what works out.

Comment: thanks for your kind response sir... sorry for i did not 
 mentioned above that i'm developing an outlook application (specifically outlook mail application for office 365)
 but this  application i am developing for outlook  requires user's credentials to login considering that i am outsourcing
 another service outside office 365 ..it's like salesforce for office 365 etc.!
 so.. is there a way where i can apply single sign on  . where i login to my office 365 account my application also in outlook weLL 
 login as weLL..! hoping for more answer sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Office365 uses ADFS to authenticate users against your Organization's Active Directory. Once you have a session with the ADFS (i.e. you've logged in once), then further requests to applications which are using the same ADFS server do not require you to login.

Comment: thanks for your kind response sir... sorry for i did not 
 mentioned above that i'm developing an outlook application (specifically outlook mail application for office 365)
 but this  application i am developing for outlook  requires user's credentials to login considering that i am outsourcing
 another service outside office 365 ..it's like salesforce for office 365 etc.!
 so.. is there a way where i can apply single sign on  . where i login to my office 365 account my application also in outlook weLL 
 login as weLL..! hoping for more answer sir :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of samples on the github repo from the training this team provides.  This [one](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3653/O3653-2%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20Office%20365%20APIs%20for%20Calendar%2C%20Mail%2C%20and%20Contacts) specifically walks through the connection to the Contacts, Mail and Calendar API using Azure AD Service and the Discovery Service. It is the lab associated with the Microsoft Virtual Academy course "[Deep Dive Integrating Office 365 into your Web Apps](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/deep-dive-integrate-office-365-apis-in-your-web-apps)".  The lab is in section 3 of the course, but recommend viewing the entire content.

Also, note that this is based on the API released in Oct 2014.  At Build 2015, there is a preview released of the new Unified API.  You can see more about this from the related [session](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/3-641) at build.  It will work with your existing code in the future as shown in the session, but something to be aware of for those coming after the Unified API is eventually released.

Visit [dev.office.com](http://dev.office.com) for all of your Office 365 development needs.

Comment: thanks for your kind response sir... sorry for i did not 
 mentioned above that i'm developing an outlook application (specifically outlook mail application for office 365)
 but this  application i am developing for outlook  requires user's credentials to login considering that i am outsourcing
 another service outside office 365 ..it's like salesforce for office 365 etc.!
 so.. is there a way where i can apply single sign on  . where i login to my office 365 account my application also in outlook weLL 
 login as weLL..! hoping for more answer sir :)